# ListView selection listener: error no suitable method found for addListener(<anonymous ChangeListener<String>>)

Tags: listview, javafx, selection, changelistener

this is about implementing a selection Listener to a ListView.

```
listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(content.getListContent()));
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
         @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) {
                  System.out.println("Selected item: " + s2);
        }
    });
```

I get this error message:

```
error: no suitable method found for addListener(<anonymous ChangeListener<String>>)
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
method Observable.addListener(InvalidationListener) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; <anonymous ChangeListener<String>> cannot be converted to InvalidationListener)
method ObservableValue.addListener(ChangeListener<? super Warning>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; <anonymous ChangeListener<String>> cannot be converted to ChangeListener<? super Warning>)
```

I don't know how to fix this. Anybody can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `listView`. What is the return type of `content.getListContent()`?

Comment: The return type of `content,getListContent()` is `List<Warning>` and the `ListView` is also type `ListView<Warning>`.

Comment: That actually is not consistent with the error message.

Comment: I am sorry, the types are `Warning`, I edited my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing from the error message that you declared the list view as

```
private ListView<Warning> listView ;
```

and that the return type of `content.getContentList()` is `List<Warning>` (or something that is a subinterface or implementation of that).

`ListView<T>.getSelectionModel()` returns a `MultipleSelectionModel<T>` (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#getSelectionModel--)), so `listView.getSelectionModel()` is giving you a `MultipleSelectionModel<Warning>`.

`MultipleSelectionModel<T>.selectedItemProperty()` returns a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<T>` (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty--)), so `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()` evaluates to a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Warning>`.

Finally, `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<T>` inherits a `addListener(ChangeListener<? super T>)` method from `ObservableValue<T>` ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-)), so you need to pass in a `ChangeListener<T>` where `T` is `Warning` or some superclass of it.

So you need

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Warning>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Warning> observableValue, Warning s, Warning s2) {
        System.out.println("Selected item: " + s2);
    }
});
```

Note that using Java8 lambdas and type inference will allow you to sidestep the whole issue:

```
listView.getSelectionModel().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("Selected item: "+newValue);
});
```

If you use this, a decent IDE will also be able to infer that `newValue` is a `Warning` here, and give you access to its methods, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes you don't recognize the simplest errors.

Comment: @GrosseGrille The error message is pretty useful here. Also, note that using up to date language features can completely avoid these kinds of errors. See update to answer.